# ViewPagerIndicator - How to avoid reload data in fragment each time returned

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

I am using Jake Wharton's [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to make a swipeable tab. Currently i can make it works in my app, with 4 tabs in it. But apparently each fragment is re-create when i change page/tab. For example, if I am in tab A, change to tab C, and back to tab A, the A tab's fragment is recreate again, not just bring the old one to front of the page.

I try to follow example of the library. Here is how my code looks like :

**ProfileViewPagerActivity**

```
private static final String[] TAB_TITLES = new String[] { "Info",
        "Personal Event", "Favorite", "Attending" };

TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;
int action;
User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);
    action = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.LOAD_WHAT, Constants.LOAD_MY_PROFILE);
    user = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constants.USER);
    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}
```

and here is the adapter as a class inside ProfileViewPagerActivity

**TestFragmentAdapter**

```
private int mCount = TAB_TITLES.length;


    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);          
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return UserInfoFragment.newInstance(action,user);

        case 1:
            return EventListFragment.newInstance(user.getUsername(), Constants.LIST_MINE, action);

        case 2:
            return EventListFragment.newInstance(user.getUsername(), Constants.LIST_FAVORITE, action);

        case 3:
            return EventListFragment.newInstance(user.getUsername(), Constants.LIST_ATTENDED, action);
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TAB_TITLES[position].toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }
```

Using codes above, the fragment re-create itself each time I change tab. I try to make a different approach, such as calling newInstance() method for each fragment inside TestFragmentAdapter constructor, and then just call the fragment object i already have in the getItem method, and it still not work.

Another solution i already tried is to saveInstanceState in each fragment, but not works too. Am i missing something? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, my mistake, i guess it's not "reinstantiated fragment" related question. After doing more debugging, i found that only data being reloaded again if the fragment showed in FragmentAdapter. In my fragment, i load data from web server in the OnCreateView method. From the android docs, i guess i should load data that I need in OnCreate method to solve this problem, am i right? thanks.

Comment: Based on my updated questions, i take @Neoh comment in his answer below is corrected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Android developers [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) on `FragmentPagerAdapter`:*The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.*

I believe android has its own mechanism to preserve the memory. If you are not convinced, you can always declare your fragments first:

```
private int mCount = TAB_TITLES.length;

private UserInfoFragment fragment0; // first fragment
private EventListFragment [] fragmentAt; // fragment 2,3,4

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

    fragmentAt = new EventListFragment[mCount-1];
    ...
}
```

Then in your `TestFragmentAdapter`:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        if(fragment0 == null) {
            fragment0 = UserInfoFragment.newInstance(action,user);
        }
        return fragment0;

    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        if(fragmentAt[position-1] == null) {
            fragmentAt[position-1] = EventListFragment.newInstance(user.getUsername(), Constants.LIST_ATTENDED, action);
        }
        return fragmentAt[position-1];
    }
}
```

This way, the fragments are guaranteed to be created only once.

Comment: I already tried to implement your code given above like I said before "I try to make a different approach, such as calling newInstance() method for each fragment inside TestFragmentAdapter constructor, and then just call the fragment object i already have in the getItem method, and it still not work."

Comment: what is still not working? the `getItem()` must be called when you swipe pages, but at least the fragment is not reinstantiated again.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I've edited my question. Please take a look, maybe you have an advice for me, @Neoh . Thanks.

Comment: To answer your new edit: Yes, you are right, all data that are created only once should be put in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make your TestFragmentAdapter extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.